# Create a Christmas Tree

Tags: c, formatting

This function draws a Christmas tree (with an angel on top) with text (AKA, ASCII art).

```
#define ARRSZ(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))

void drawChristmasTree (int height) {
    const char * const angel[] = { " ._.", "(\\o/)", ")/|\\(", "/_*_\\", };
    const char stars[] = "***************************************";
    int i;
    int offset = 20 - height;

    if ((height < ARRSZ(angel)) || (height > ARRSZ(stars)/2)) {
        printf("The height has to be at least %zu and no more than %zu.\n",
               ARRSZ(angel), ARRSZ(stars)/2);
        return;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        printf("%*s%s\n",
               height - (i < ARRSZ(angel) ? ARRSZ(angel) : i + 1), "",
               (i < ARRSZ(angel)) ? angel[i] : &stars[ARRSZ(stars) - 2*i]);
    }
    printf("%*s%c\n", height - 2, "", '*');
    printf("%*s%c\n", height - 2, "", '*');
}
```

For size 10, this code produces:

```
       ._.
      (\o/)
      )/|\(
      /_*_\
     *******
    *********
   ***********
  *************
 ***************
*****************
        *
        *
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Compiler warnings

Always compile with warnings turned on.  Your compiler should have warned you that `offset` is an unused variable.  My compiler also complained about passing an unsigned int as an argument to `printf("%*")` with `height - (i < ARRSZ(angel) ? ARRSZ(angel) : i + 1)`.

### Error handling

The output should either be a Christmas tree or nothing at all.  Printing an error message in place of a tree is just mean.

[image: How the Grinch Stole Christmas]

If you must print an error message, print it to `stderr`!

### Code formatting

Why not make the angel look like an angel in your code?  Granted, the double backslashes interfere with the alignment, but at least you could try.

```
const char * const angel[] = { " ._.",
                              "(\\o/)",
                               ")/|\\(",
                               "/_*_\\", };
```

### Looping

With those conditional expressions within the loop, you might as well split it into two loops:

```
for (i = 0; i < ARRSZ(angel); ++i) {
    printf("%*s%s\n", height - (int)ARRSZ(angel), "", angel[i]);
}
for (; i < height; ++i) {
    printf("%*s%s\n", height - i - 1, "", stars + ARRSZ(stars) - 2*i);
}
```

Here, I've also rewritten `&stars[ARRSZ(stars) - 2*i]` using the more idiomatic pointer arithmetic.

### Alternate solution

If you ensure that each line of the angel has the same length, then you could also write the `printf()` calls as

```
const char * const angel[] = { " ._. ",
                              "(\\o/)",
                               ")/|\\(",
                               "/_*_\\", };

for (i = 0; i < ARRSZ(angel); ++i) {
    printf(" %*s\n", (int)(height - ARRSZ(angel) + ARRSZ(angel[0]) / 2), angel[i]);
}
for (; i < height; ++i) {
    printf("%*.*s\n", height + i - 2, 2 * i - 1, stars);
}
```